# Was the "Reverse Universe" ever returned to?

Tags: star-trek, parallel-universe, star-trek-tas

In the *Star Trek: The Animated Series* episode "The Counter-Clock Incident", the Enterprise discovers and travels to a parallel dimension in which time flows in reverse. Supernovas represent the birth of stars, empty space itself is bright white, and *people age in reverse*.

This discovery of a literal cure for aging would seemingly represent a boon not only to the Federation but the galaxy, at least until

> The discovery of the Ba'ku fountain of youth in 2375 by Admiral Dougherty.

Is this "Reverse Universe" ever returned to in Star Trek? Even if the Federation decides against immortality for its citizens, the Reverse Universe represents an opportunity to "seek out new life and new civilizations" that Starfleet ought to be interested in. The episode also ends with at least some of the Reverse Universe inhabitants aware of Kirk's universe, so some of *them* might attempt future incursions (which may show up *before* this episode from the perspective of Kirk's timeline, but hey).

I do note that the well-known "Mirror Universe" was originally created for a one-off episode but became a grand story arc many years later, so there's no reason to not return to the Reverse Universe unless the writers have determined that it is silly and contradictory to our current understanding of physics (which I agree with, but then Star Trek has plenty of silliness and physics-contradicting stuff already).

Comment: Even the worst "silly and contradictory" things from TAS have been exceeded by live shows.  Voyager had a time reversed culture episode like this TAS episode had.